# How to prevent Toplevel() from closing both windows python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I was testing the Toplevel() feature of python Tkinter and I was wondering if a user closes one window how do I keep the other one from closing as well?

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
top = Toplevel()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling [`transient`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#wm.Wm.wm_transient-method), closing toplevel will not close the all windows.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
top = Toplevel()
top.title('TopLevel window')
top.transient(root) # <------

root.mainloop()
```